# Passing tensorDataset or Dataloader to skorch

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, skorch

I want to apply cross validation in Pytorch using skorch, so I prepared my model and my tensorDataset which returns (image,caption and captions_length) and so it has X and Y, so I'll not be able to set Y in the method

```
net.fit(dataset)
```

but when I tried that I got an error :

> ValueError: Stratified CV requires explicitly passing a suitable y

Here's part of my code:

```
start = time.time()
net = NeuralNetClassifier(
        decoder, criterion= nn.CrossEntropyLoss,
        max_epochs=args.epochs,
        lr=args.lr,
        optimizer=optim.SGD,
        device='cuda',  # uncomment this to train with CUDA
       )
net.fit(dataset, y=None)
end = time.time()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are (implicitly) using the internal CV split of skorch which uses a stratified split in case of the `NeuralNetClassifier` which in turn needs information about the labels beforehand.

When passing `X` and `y` to `fit` separately this works fine since `y` is accessible at all times. The problem is that you are using `torch.dataset.Dataset` which is lazy and does not give you access to `y` directly, hence the error.

Your options are the following.

#### Set `train_split=None` to disable the internal CV split

```python
net = NeuralNetClassifier(
    train_split=None,
)
```

You will lose internal validation and, as such, features like early stopping.

#### Split your data beforehand

Split your dataset into two datasets, `dataset_train` and `dataset_valid`, 
then use [`skorch.helper.predefined_split`](https://skorch.readthedocs.io/en/stable/helper.html#skorch.helper.predefined_split):

```python
net = NeuralNetClassifier(
    train_split=predefined_split(dataset_valid),
)
```

You lose nothing but depending on your data this might be complicated.

#### Extract your `y` and pass it to fit

```python
y_train = np.array([y for X, y in iter(my_dataset)])
net.fit(my_dataset, y=y_train)
```

This only works if your `y` fits into memory. Since you are using `TensorDataset` you can also do the following to extract your `y`:

```python
y_train = my_dataset.y
```

Comment: Hello nemo thanks for your reply but I'm not only passing X during the training so will skorch be able to to handle that!

Comment: When passing a dataset to `.fit` skorch expects the dataset to contain `(X, y)` so yes, skorch handles this case as you would expect. The `y` is only necessary for the split before training.